# java.io.IOException: Stream closed, but only when run from jar

Tags: java

The program runs perfectly when you run it straight from the class. However, when the program is created into a jar using the cmd jar command, I always get a runtime error when I launch the program, and the program also continues to get stuck in a loop forever. Sorry that I can't tell you match, I'm very new to java.

Here is my method that is causing issues:

```
private static void pinyin()
{
    try
    {
        HanyuPinyinOutputFormat format = new HanyuPinyinOutputFormat();
        format.setCaseType(HanyuPinyinCaseType.LOWERCASE);
        format.setToneType(HanyuPinyinToneType.WITH_TONE_MARK);
        format.setVCharType(HanyuPinyinVCharType.WITH_U_UNICODE);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (!lines[i].equals(""))
            {
                lines[i] += " ";
            }
            String[] part = lines[i].split("#");
            part[2] = "";
            for (int y = 0; y < part[0].length(); y++)
            {

                String st = PinyinHelper.toHanyuPinyinStringArray(part[0].charAt(y), format)[0];
                part[2] = part[2] + st + " ";

            }
            lines[i] = part[0] + "#" + part[1] + "#" + (part[2].charAt(0) + "").toUpperCase() + part[2].substring(1, part[2].length() - 1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Runtime Error" + e);
    }
}
```

it appears to be the line `String st = PinyinHelper.toHanyuPinyinStringArray(part[0].charAt(y), format)[0];` that is causing the error.
The error that I get when I run from the jar is:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.ChineseToPinyinResource.initializeResource(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.ChineseToPinyinResource.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.ChineseToPinyinResource.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.ChineseToPinyinResource$ChineseToPinyinResourceHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.ChineseToPinyinResource.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.PinyinHelper.getUnformattedHanyuPinyinStringArray(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.PinyinHelper.getFormattedHanyuPinyinStringArray(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.pinyin4j.PinyinHelper.toHanyuPinyinStringArray(Unknown Source)
    at PinYin.pinyin(PinYin.java:101)
    at PinYin.main(PinYin.java:30)
    at Launch$5.actionPerformed(Launch.java:138)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Runtime Errorjava.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at PinYin.pinyin(PinYin.java:108)
        at PinYin.main(PinYin.java:30)
        at Launch$5.actionPerformed(Launch.java:138)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is what I use to create the jar:

```
jar -cmf *.mf SortRandomDeletePin.jar *.class net\*
```

Please help me any way you can, I'm stumped.

Also note that my program imports a class from another jar.

Comment: It is probably not a jar issue, chceck the log message java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 that refers to a line in your pinyin class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code of [ChineseToPinyinResource](https://github.com/belerweb/pinyin4j/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pinyin4j/ChineseToPinyinResource.java), you can see that two files have to be in the classpath (*) , namely `/pinyindb/unicode_to_hanyu_pinyin.txt` and `/pinyindb/multi_pinyin.txt` .

```
private void initializeResource() {
    try {
        final String resourceName = "/pinyindb/unicode_to_hanyu_pinyin.txt";
        final String resourceMultiName = "/pinyindb/multi_pinyin.txt";

        setUnicodeToHanyuPinyinTable(new Trie());
        getUnicodeToHanyuPinyinTable().load(ResourceHelper.getResourceInputStream(resourceName));

        getUnicodeToHanyuPinyinTable().loadMultiPinyin(ResourceHelper.getResourceInputStream(resourceMultiName));

        getUnicodeToHanyuPinyinTable().loadMultiPinyinExtend();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Make sure that those files are available in the classpath at runtime, and with their exact path.

(*) : The [ResouceHelper](https://github.com/belerweb/pinyin4j/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pinyin4j/ResourceHelper.java) class does a `ResourceHelper.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)` .